# Is appending okay in DBMS?

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, datagridview, erd

I have this project that records offenses of students.

Here's how it goes.

Imagine a girl in one class committed cheating.  Her data is then added to the table.  Then the same girl did another offense - vandalism.  Her information is once again stored in the database.  So it would look something like this in the table. (Done on the same date)

```
Record Number    Student_ID        Name      OffenseCode    OffenseDesc
      1            178003         Girly           N          Cheating
      2            178003         Girly           B          Vandalism
```

Then I have my bridge entity which has the following data upon Girly's entries

```
RecordNumber    OffenseNumber   Student_ID  OffenseCode  Count  Remarks
      1               1           178003          N        0    WARNING
      2               2           178003          B        1    CALL PARENT
```

Then when in the DataGridView (using VB.NET) this happens

```
Record Number    Student_ID        Name      OffenseCode    OffenseDesc
      1            178003         Girly           N          Cheating
      2            178003         Girly           B          Vandalism
      3            178003         Girly           N          Cheating
      4            178003         Girly           B          Vandalism
```

I INNER JOINED my tables to get that result.  If you must know the tables

student - Record_Number (PK), Student_ID, Name, Class, DateCommitted
bridge - Record_Number (PK), OffenseNum (PK), Student_ID, Offense_Code, Count, Remarks
offenses - OffenseNum (PK), OffenseCode, OffenseDesc

What do I  do to fix the above problem?

Comment: So, `StudentId` is *not* the PK for a student?  What purpose does it serve then?  What exactly is that first table, it seems to duplicate everything in the "bridge" table

Comment: @Plutonix Because when I set it as the PK and I want to insert the same data into the database it just creates an error saying that data already exists.  So I made the record number as the PK to make it function as a log book style kind of recording.

Comment: @NoobCoder That's fine, but then it's not your student table any more. If a student changes their name, or class, you have to update every record in the table for that student.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I see.  Well, this database only allows to change their names.  And by "..you have to update every record in the table for that student.." do you mean everything related to the student's profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what your table schema should look like:

1. **Student** — StudentID (PK), StudentName, Class
2. **OffenseType** — OffenseCode (PK), OffenseDesc
3. **Incident** — Record_Number (PK), StudentID, OffenseCode, DateCommitted, Remarks

You might even need an additional table for the Remarks, since several people may need to comment on an incident before it is fully resolved.

Then the query for your grid will look like this:

```
SELECT RecordNumber, StudentID, StudentName, OffenseCode, OffenseDesc
FROM Incident i
INNER JOIN OffenseType o ON o.OffenseCode = i.OffenseCode
INNER JOIN Student s on s.StudentID = i.StudentID
```

Comment: My tables however between **Student** and **OffenseType** are of a M:N Relationship.  Meaning I would have needed a bridge/composite entity in between the two tables to solve the relationship.

In this case, what would be the output?  Will student Girly be shown twice with two different offenses?

Comment: In this case, the `Incident` table **is** that intersection (bridge/composite) link you're talking about. Intersection or bridge links almost always turn out to be an entity in their own right. With the table schema and query I presented, a student named "Girly" with two offenses would show up twice (once for each offense), but not four times as she does in the sample from the question.

Comment: I see.  I've noticed you did not include the Count attribute since it would just mess up the table, right?

Comment: If I included it, it would be a computed column. Try not to store data that can be computed without good cause.

Comment: The purpose of the Count attribute is that it keeps track of how many offenses are done by a student and thus is related to remarks.

3 offenses = suspension 

Something like this.

Comment: It's still a computed value, since you can always use count(*), row_number, or a rank function to get the count on the fly